# Additional Text Files missing from Artifact JAR Build in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I've been using this strategy for awhile, I would include my SQL statements in the JAR Artifact for my project, and read it at run-time using getResourceAsStream().

However in this new project IntelliJ fails to add these files to my JAR.

See image:

[image: Broken JAR Project]

However, in another project it seems to work fine.

[image]

I've attempted to close/reopen IntelliJ, no fix.

I've attempted to delete my Artifact build and recreate from scratch, no fix.

Putting the files manually into the JAR works, but I need this to be part of the build process, and generation for the JAR.

I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I've updated from IntelliJ IDEA 15 to IntelliJ IDEA 16, with no change in the  Artifact JAR.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer.

If you create your project as a MAVEN project it will have this behavior and therefore you will need to figure out how to include fix this when its setup as a maven project.

OR.

You remove the configuration in the project.iml file.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsManager.isMavenModule="true" type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
```

To:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
```

A rebuild of my project generated an Artifact JAR correctly.